# How can I load CSS styles using Webpack in React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am having an issue with my React app. I have added Webpack and it is compiling successfully but, at the moment of serving the content, the app shows no styles at all.

This is what I have so far in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/build');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/src');
// This is the main configuration object.
// Here, you write different options and tell Webpack what to do
module.exports = {

  experiments: {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    topLevelAwait: true,
    layers: true // optional, with some bundlers/frameworks it doesn't work without
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  // Path to your entry point. From this file Webpack will begin its work
  entry: [APP_DIR + '/index.js', APP_DIR + '/index.css', APP_DIR + '/App.css'],

  // Path and filename of your result bundle.
  // Webpack will bundle all JavaScript into this file
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  // Default mode for Webpack is production.
  // Depending on mode Webpack will apply different things
  // on the final bundle. For now, we don't need production's JavaScript 
  // minifying and other things, so let's set mode to development
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              { loader: 'style-loader' },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                },
              },
              { loader: 'sass-loader' },
              { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
            ],
        },
    ]
  }
};
```

Is there anything I am missing to get my css to work? I only have two files, located at `/src`: `App.css` and `index.css`. None of them seem to be loaded and I have no errors in the console.

Comment: do you have that styles files imported in your component?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: The styles that doesn't seem to work are @font-face mainly.

Answer (score -1):

```
  rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|less|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                  'file-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: false
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I am getting an error with sass: ERROR in ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/url-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[0]!./src/index.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ export default __webpack_public_path__ + "6f6dd912a16a6c09d1a9bacbcbe60aa4.css";